# MVC3 Search Screen with Multiple model and lookup table

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, entity

I am going to develop a search page where I will have multiple fields comming from differenet models (entity).  Also, I have multiple `DropDownList`s on the same screen whose values will be populated from a lookup table.

I would like to know (in this scenario) what is the best approach.  Should I create a `ViewModel` and pass that model to my view? Or do I need a different approach?

But I am not sure how I should handle my dropdown field, which is populating from lookup table.

Also, on submitting the page, how should I get those values in my next search details screen to get all the records from db?

I am using MVC3 with EF 4.2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Having a ViewModel with necessary properties ( your search criteria) is the way to go.
When you do a HttpGet action for your search load all datas from the look up tables and load to the properties ( ex : States etc..).

```
  public ActionResult Search()
  {
    SearchViewModel objVM=new SearchViewModel();
    objVM.States=MyService.GetStates();
    objVM.Type=MyService.GetUserTypes();    
    return objVM.    
  }

  [HttpPost]  
  public ActionResult Search(SearchViewModel objVM)
  {
      if(ModelState.IsValid)
      {
         //Go for the search and return results

      } 
      return View(objVm); 
  }
```

Comment: So i will create a viewmodel with necessary search property only. that means i no need to ref my entire models property in my viewmodel.

Comment: One more thing, while searching the result, i need to first search some key field with external db, if found then it will search the entire field with current db. My question is I have already a query available for the search criteria, can i use that query on my EF? do you have any sample or links to achive this.

Comment: @PrasantaBiswal :Yes use whatever fields you want in your search form as properties.

Answer (score 1):

Absolutely, the best approach is definitely to use a ViewModel.  Something like this would suffice:

```
public class Model1
{
    public string Prop1 { get; set; }
}

public class Model2
{
    public string Prop2 { get; set; }
}

public class ViewModel1
{
    public Model1 Model1 { get; set; }
    public Model2 Model2 { get; set; }
    public SelectList DropDownItems { get; set; }
}
```

You'd populate the `SelectList` with an amount of `SelectListItem` objects in your Controller's Action Method that will pass this ViewModel to the View.